# Do we need to use off-policy methods for policy shaping?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

Let's say that there is a reinforcement learning task and an agent in a environment. I want a human teacher to manually modify the policy of the agent (policy shaping) to speed up the learning of the agent. Do I have to use off-policy methods or I can get away with on-policy? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Policy Gradients for this which is on-policy. One of the most straightforward ways to do that is to provide the teacher/expert's probabilities over actions at each time-step. Then you can use the usual policy gradient loss plus the cross entropy between expert's actions distribution and agent's action distribution:

$$\mathcal{L(\boldsymbol{\theta})} =(R_t-V_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(\boldsymbol{s}_t)) \log \pi_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(a_t|\boldsymbol{s}_t) + \lambda H(\pi_{expert},\pi_{\boldsymbol{\theta}})$$

You could get a look at this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03835.pdf) for basic ways to affect on-policy learning in PG methods.

On the why this works, I will give you a descriptive explanation: Cross entropy is related to KL divergence which is a "measure" of the distance between two distributions. With the extra term in the Loss function we are trying to minimize the distance between the expert's distribution and agent's distribution (i.e. making the agent's one more similar to the expert's one).

Comment: Great answer. Simple, yet effective. Thank you! Can this method be used when we have the expert feedback not always i.e sparsely? And do you think policy shaping: https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/papers/policy-ijcai2015.pdf can be used on online methods? On the paper above it is used for Q learning.

Comment: You are welcome :) If the feedback for action $a_t$ is given delayed then this is a very difficult problem. If you want to provide feedback at specific time during training you can tune $\lambda$. But if you do not have the probabilities of the expert at every time step then you need a model for this that you can train with Supervised Learning. The method in the paper is not for Policy Gradients. Instead, it is suitable for Value-based methods as it tunes the softmax of the value function. For PGs there are many methods that you can look at (e.g. keyword: imitation learning)

Comment: Thanks, I will check imitation learning :) And for PG methods we sample from the policy distribution, right? Do you know if we can apply different sampling method here for ex. to increase exploration of different outputs?

Comment: Yes, we sample from the policy. You can use a weighted random sampler, were the weights will be the probabilities from the policy output. Additionally you can add the policy entropy in your loss function which encourages exploration. You can take a look at the Asynchronous Methods for RL to see an example of this loss function.